# rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need help to solve this problem.. im using hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165076/hattan@hattan-satellite-c850-a987:%7E$-rosmake---rosdep-install-pi_speech_tutorialusage:-rosmake-%5Boptions%5D-%5Bpackage%5D...--rosmake:-error:-no-such-option:---rosdep-install/) by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That option was removed in ROS Fuerte, and is no longer valid in ROS Hydro. Please search for duplicate answers before posting:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/39571/rosmake-error-no-such-option-rosdep-install/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/38291/no-such-option-rosdep-install/

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2